# How can I extract a row from a DataFrame as a Series, with the column names in the DataFrame as the row indices in the Series?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
   x y z
a  0 1 2
b  3 4 5
c  6 7 8
```

How can I extract, say, row `b` as a `Series` such that I now have:

```
x 3
y 4
z 5
```

Comment: `s = df.loc['b']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) will return a Series when you give it a single label.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 3, 6],
                   'y': [1, 4, 7],
                   'z': [2, 5, 8]},
                  index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

s = df.loc['b']
print(type(s))
print(s)
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
x    3
y    4
z    5
Name: b, dtype: int64
```